# How to deploy Docker container automated in Azure Service Fabric with TeamCity?

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, teamcity, azure-service-fabric

I want to deploy a Docker container in a Azure Service Fabric. For this I implemented a Node.js service and wrote my dockerfile. I tested the service on my local machine with Docker and it worked. My next step was to build the Docker image on TeamCity. I use a Docker runner for it and it worked too. Now I want to deploy this image to an Azure Service Fabric cluster. But I did not find any documentation.

My idea is to use the artifact (docker image) from my build step, and deploy it directly to a Service Fabric cluster. Is this possible? If not, how can I deploy my image there?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use your build server to create a [container image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)
2. From the build server, push the image to a container registry like [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/).
3. Deploy a [Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview) service that uses the image to run a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux).

Comment: Can you explain the step between the container registry and the service fabric a bit more in detail? I want that the service fabric detect every change in my container registry and deploy my container new.

Comment: Sure, make sure that every image version you push has a unique tag. This could be the ID of your build for example. In the release pipeline, you specify that tag in the service manifest (or docker-compose yaml file). When you deploy your updated service version, SF will upgrade to the newer version. SF will not detect changes to image versions by itself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-container-image

Comment: Okay that sounds simple. Where I have to trigger the service update? Manually in the SF explorer or where?

Comment: That would be (one of) the last step(s) of your CI/CD pipeline, for example by using PowerShell or CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps   or  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli

Comment: Okay, a last question: Before I can deploy the container to the SF I have to set up manually a SF application for container with VS?

Comment: Yep, have a look at this walkthrough: https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a container to SF you have deploy a service fabric application.

An application is just a manifest that defines the services and containers that an application is built on.

These links will guide you through this:

- [Create your first Service Fabric container application on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers)
- [Create your first Service Fabric container application on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux)

Currently there is no way to deploy a container without setup an application on SF and I don't think they will add a similar feature like docker `docker run xyz` or kubernetes `kubectl run --image=nginx nginx-app` anytime soon.

Applications are the foundations of SF to define how resources are arranged together.

Maybe they could provide a feature to auto create an application for standalone containers, if you really need this, I would suggest you create as a feature request on their [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues)

Comment: I read these examples but I thougth there is a way without creating a SF application with Visual Studio. I searched a way to deploy the service directly .

Comment: I've added more info